# Example of recurrence relation without closed form expression?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Can give an example of a recurrence relation for which there does not exist a closed form expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p_1 = 2$ and let $p_i = \min\{x\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{1\} \;\colon p_j \nmid x \;\forall j\in [1,i-1] \}$ for $i \geq 2$.

Comment: I believe that this answer is wrong. Qiaochu Yuan's answer is much better.

Answer (score 2):

The quadratic recurrence relation $x_{n+1} = r x_n (1 - x_n)$ (iterating the [logistic map](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html)) exhibits chaotic behavior for various values of $r$, which at least rules out any straightforward closed forms.

Comment: And of course there is the hailstone sequence (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), but I think the logistic map is a nicer example because it's defined by a polynomial, and hence shows that the theory of linear recurrences doesn't generalize in any straightforward way to polynomial recurrences of any higher degree.